# GMSCoreResources.bundle not loaded

Tags: iphone, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to use the Google Maps API, however I'm getting this error when I open up the map in my application:

> Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0x155a7f70 /GoogleMapTest.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCoreResources.bundle> (not loaded)

Anyone else getting this error? Here's the code I'm using when launching the map within my app:

```
- (void)loadView {
// Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
// coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:40.468193
                                                        longitude:-74.445184
                                                             zoom:6];
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
self.view = mapView_;

// Creates a marker in the center of the map.
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
marker.title = @"Sydney";
marker.snippet = @"Australia";
marker.map = mapView_;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I'm getting that too. No fix as of yet.

Comment: When was the maps for google iOS SDK released? Has someone filed a complaint with them? I've been looking around for days on Google and have still yet to find an answer! GOOGLE: FIX THIS NOW!

Comment: Yeah also google maps doesn't run using armv7s architecture, only armv7. which blows.